# Angular interpolation syntax: count all children objects from all children objects

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following classes:

```
export class VrpInstance {
  routes: Array<Route>;
}

export class Route {
  points: Array<number>;
}
```

In the HTML file I have a list of `VrpInstance` objects, and for each of them, I want to display the total number of points from all of its routes using the interpolation syntax.

I tried using:
`{{[].concat.apply([], vrpInstance.routes).length}}` and `vrpInstance.routes.flat()` but none of them work as intended.

**Desired behaviour:**
for a `vrpInstance` object that looks like the one below, I would like to output length 6 (since I have in total 6 points: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]).

```
{
 "routes" : 
  [ 
    { "points" : [1, 2, 3]},
    { "points" : [4, 5, 6]} 
  ]
}
```

How can this be done **using the interpolation syntax**?

Comment: You shouldnt do that in the html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid calling methods from your template because the method will be called every time change detection runs. If the value can change, you should use a pipe since it wont run everytime angular change detection runs but only when the value change.

A simple pipe that takes an array(VrpInstance) as a parameter:

```
@Pipe({name: 'calculatePoint'})
export class CalculatePointPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(route: VrpInstance): number {
    const total = 0;
    route.routes.forEach((points: Array<number>) => {
        total += point.length;
    })
    return total;
  }
}
```

And then in the HTML:

```
{{ routes | calculatePoint }}
```